# Definition of congruence modulo ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $a$ is an ideal in $\mathcal O_K,K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ . What does $\rho\equiv0\pmod{a}$ mean? Does it mean that $\rho=ta$ for $t\in \mathcal O_K$ .

Comment: Rather it means $\rho\in a$. If $I$ is an ideal, then $x\equiv y\pmod I$ means that $x-y\in I$.

Comment: thanks for your answer!